# Terraform: lambda_function_association cloudfront distribution s3 origin m

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting this terraform change when I run `terraform plan`, and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
    ~ module.***.***.***.aws_cloudfront_distribution.cf_distribution
      default_cache_behavior.0.lambda_function_association.*******.event_type:     "origin-response" => ""
      default_cache_behavior.0.lambda_function_association.*******.include_body:   "false" => "false"
      default_cache_behavior.0.lambda_function_association.*******.lambda_arn:     "arn:***********************************" => ""
      default_cache_behavior.0.lambda_function_association.~*******.event_type:   "" => "origin-response"
      default_cache_behavior.0.lambda_function_association.~*******.include_body: "" => "false"
      default_cache_behavior.0.lambda_function_association.~*******.lambda_arn:   "" => "${var.lambda_arn}"
```

I have tried adding `include_body` in the modules repo which is sourced for the module. However, it still is giving me the same error.

Kind of stuck on this and cannot find a solution.

Comment: What is the full error message? Where does it originate from?

Comment: It is coming when I run terraform plan, as a "change". The module is from a repo, and it does include all the 3 variables in it.